# WebGL immediate mode

Tags: opengl, javascript, html5, webgl

I know that WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0 and that `glBegin` and `glEnd` have been removed and replaced with vertex buffer objects. I understand that VBOs are faster and use less code but is there a library or add-on for JavaScript / WebGL that re-implements these functions?

After more research, I have discovered that this functionality is called immediate mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what your rationale is for doing this. You might want to ask a new question about the problems you're running into that would inspire you to look for such a utility.

There is a library called [LightGL](http://www.amsqr.com/2012/07/using-opengl-inmediate-mode-in-webgl.html) that attempts to do what you're asking. This is just a simulation of immediate mode, since true immediate mode is not supported. It's not really very close to immediate mode either, but it's likely as close as you're going to get.

Comment: I was actually looking at light.js on GitHub when I saw your message. What does it mean when it says that it has no fixed function lighting?

Comment: As for why I am lookin into this, I built a simple 2d engine in LWJGL using immediate mode and I am looking to port it as easily as possible!

Comment: Fixed function lights are immediate mode lights (so you can only do shader level lights). I don't want to start a discussion here about it, you should ask your questions about it in chat if you want further information. If the questions warrant it, you might also ask new questions.